# how do I sort the result of @distinctUnionOfObjects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I am using the following code to get my unique order types:

```
NSArray   *orderTypes = [self.ordersPlacedList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.OrderStatus"];
```

Works great except it is not sorted, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just calling `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` (or one of the related functions) on the results?

```
NSArray *orderTypes = [[self.ordersPlacedList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.OrderStatus"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```